# Hide files using PHP only

Tags: php

I have to hide some files with the extensions: .png, .php, and.html from PHP.

.htaccess works fine

```
IndexIgnore *.png
IndexIgnore *.php
IndexIgnore *.html
```

But, I want to hide the files using PHP.

I use this script:

```
<?php
    $myfolder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    $handle = opendir("$myfolder");
    while($name = readdir($handle)) 
        echo "$name<br>";
    }
    closedir($handle);
?>
```

But, I still can see the files.
Thanks to everyone who can help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it using regex

```
<?php
    // Regex with which to hide some file types
    $ignore_regex = '/(\.png|\.php|\.html)$/';

    $myfolder = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
    $handle = opendir("$myfolder");
    while($name = readdir($handle)) {
        // Check if this name matches the ignore regex
        if(preg_match($ignore_regex, $name)) {
            continue;
        }
        echo "$name<br>";
    }
    closedir($handle);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP reads the file system directly, it doesn't read the file through the webserver.  Thus it ignores the .htaccess file.

You need to manually check for these file types in your loop, and just ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has function called [glob](http://www.php.net/glob) which will return files that match a pattern. That is probably what you need to use.

There is a very useful, short tutorial on [glob patterns here](http://cowburn.info/2010/04/30/glob-patterns/) as pointed out by [Rocket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket) below.

It's worth using for the name alone :)